# convert this format Tue Sep 07 2021 08:34:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in python or django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to convert this format or any timezone format to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.
format needed to be converted is - `Tue Sep 07 2021 08:34:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

can anyone help ?

Comment: You should also paste what are the efforts you have taken, what code you have written to obtain the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = 'Tue Sep 07 2021 08:34:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)'.replace('(India Standard Time)', '').rstrip()
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %Z%z').strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(datetime_object)
```

Gives output

```
2021-09-07 08:34:00
```

Hour is set to 24 hour clock

If you want 12 hour clock replace %H with %I in the above code